# Norwegian and Swedish Coastline/Shoreline Types GIS Data

Tags: raster, shapefile, data, norway, sweden

I am looking for a data source for Coastline or Shoreline data of Norway and Sweden. I have this data for Denmark, and it specifies the coastline type such as:
- Man made
- Rocky
- Sandy
- Vegetated/Marsh

I have been trawling the web, and not found much.  I am using QGIS 2.14.5 (Essen) and a vector shapefile (.SHP) or Raster data source would be best.

Answer (score 2):

The EEA (European Environment Agency) has a European coastline shapefile located here: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-coastline-for-analysis-1/gis-data/europe-coastline-shapefile

It's very detailed and contains the countries you need. You'll have to demarcate them into the relevant countries using another layer though.

The EEA is a great source for this kind of spatial data.

Answer (score 2):

[Swedish datasets](https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Kartor-och-geografisk-information/oppna-data/) from Lantmäteriet. Create a free account and download via ftp. If you want very fine details i would recommend "GSD terrain map, vector".

Answer (score 1):

A coastline for Europe is available for download in SHP format from the of European Environment Agency's website. Note that the data is available in line and polygon format but it has **No** attribute information. This data can be downloaded from the link given below

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-coastline-for-analysis-1/gis-data/europe-coastline-shapefile

In addition to this, A Global Self-consistent, Hierarchical, High-resolution Geography Database (GSHHG) - a high-resolution geography data set, amalgamated from three databases in the public domain is also available. This dataset offers coast lines in 5 levels of resolution. You can read more about GSHHG at

http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of MFBawls answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at these datasets:
http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html
The data comes from OpenStreetMap, geofrabrik did the packing for you. 
Or you could try the plugin "QuickOSM" in QGIS. It gives you the possibility to download OSM Data for a specified extent directly.
Not sure on how the data structures for coastlines is regarding rocky/sandy/etc though.

Answer (score 0):

Norwegian data can be obtained from Kartverket.

http://data.kartverket.no/

If you wanted the vegetation information, it looks like you should:

1. Go here:
   http://data.kartverket.no/download/content/geodataprodukter?korttype=3605&aktualitet=All&datastruktur=All&dataskema=All
2. From `Karttype`, select `Vegdata`

I believe it is accessible with a free registration.